# ke_search extension of typo3 is not showing words with character length less than 4

Tags: typo3, faceted-search, typo3-9.x, typo3-extensions

I am using the ke_search extension. I indexed all the required data. All of them are showing in "Indexed content" section. But when I searched in the frontend, the titles with character length less than 4 are not displaying as output. To solve this i changed the “searchWordLength” in the extension manager setting to 2. But still the issue is not solved. What should i do more to solve this ?  (iam using typo3 version 9.5.5)

Answer (score 2):

Did you adjust the corresponding MySQL setting?

From the [ke_search documentation](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/extensions/ke_search/stable/Configuration/SearchWordLength.html):

> By default ke_search only finds words with a minimum length of four
>   characters. This corresponds to the MySQL setting `ft_min_word_len`
>   which is set to `4` by default.
>
> The value can be reduced by following theses steps:
>
> - change `ft_min_word_len` to the desired value in your MySQL configuration (eg. *my.cnf*) (default: `4`)
> - set `searchWordLength` in the extension manager setting to the same value
> - re-index your content

Comment: I changed the "searchWordLength" in extension manager setting. But, i was not able to change the MySQL configuration. How can i do that ?

Comment: This depends on your hosting environment. On a shared server, you'll most likely get no access to the MySQL server settings. Is a `my.cnf` file available in a directory on your server?

Comment: To improve the answer this could be helpful:

if you want to see the actual setting, use this mysql command
Show VARIABLES LIKE "ft_mi%"

You need admin access to the webservers mysql settings as it is a system setting.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. I was not able to find a "my.cnf" file